# Enviar email con PHP sin tiempo de espera

Tags: php

En varios sitios de mi proyecto, al enviar un formulario, este tiene la función también de enviar un email a 3 destinatarios

El caso es que tarda unos 4-5 segundos en validar el formulario porque se está enviando el email.

Lo que necesito es optimizar mi código para enviar el email más rapido

No uso Ajax

```html
<form action="borrar.php" method="post" name="formborrar" id="formborrar" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;text-align: left;width: 100px;margin: initial;">
  <input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" style="display: none;">
  <p><input class="btn" onclick="security()" id="submit_value" value="Borrar Aviso" name="submit_value"></p>
</form>
```

**Archivo uploader.php**

```html
<?php
$para  = 'compras@ejemplo.com';
 
$titulo = 'Se ha borrado un aviso por ' . $usuario;
 
ob_start();

$mensaje = "Mensaje de ejemplo";

$cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 
$cabeceras .= 'From: <avisos@ejemplo.com>' . "\r\n";

mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

He omitido varios inputs e información poco relevante

Comment: La pregunta no se entiende bien porque no explicas del todo el escenario. Por ejemplo, ¿cómo tienes organizados los archivos, todo en uno, o son archivos distintos?  ¿Usas Ajax o no? Si es no, ¿no lo usas porque no quieres o porque no lo conoces? Tu pregunta es si se puede enviar un email más rápido... eso es difícil de responder. En email se envía cuando se envía, lo que sí se puede es optimizar el código que arma los diferentes elementos para que el email se envíe. Creo que es eso lo que quieres, si no me equivoco. Pero como digo, faltan detalles para entender el contexto.

Comment: Son archivos independientes. No uso Ajax porque no lo entiendo todavía. Lo que necesito, como tu has dicho, es optimizar el código para enviar el email más rápido

Comment: Pues resulta que lo ideal en este caso sería precisamente usar Ajax. Si es que he entendido bien, con Ajax los pasos serían: 1. Desde el cliente recoger los datos que haya que recoger y validando lo que haya que validar; 2. Terminada esa etapa, envías la información al servidor para que desde allí se haga el envío del email. Eso es lo que yo entiendo. Luego en la pregunta hay cosas confusas, sin ningún detalle. Como lo que dices al principio: *este tiene la función también de enviar un email a 3 destinatarios*  ¿eso qué significa? ¿es un email con el mismo contenido? ¿es contenido fijo? ... ¿?

Comment: Entonces aprenderé Ajax, buscaba algo así, enviar el email directamente desde el servidor y ahorrar ese tiempo al cliente. Lo de enviar a destinatarios es información por si puede ser relevante. El email es dinámico, envia parte de la información que hay en el formulario

Comment: No hay problema. Desde Ajax tú puedes recoger la información que hay en el formulario una vez que éste haya sido validado (por ejemplo, puedes dejar el botón `Enviar`  desactivado hasta que la validación no ocurra). El servidor recibe la información que le mandas desde Ajax y hace el envío del email de una forma totalmente transparente para el usuario. Si el envío es exitoso puedes devolver al cliente (siempre vía Ajax) un mensaje de éxito o de error y mostrar dicho mensaje en alguna parte, como en un `div` dedicado para eso o en una barra de estado, etc. Y continuar el flujo del programa...

Comment: Me imagino, como funciona este comentario, se envia al servidor sin recargar la página, este puede tardar en enviarse varios segundos sin que el cliente (en este caso yo) lo perciba. Gracias, aprenderé ajax para optimizar mis formularios

Comment: Exacto. Esa es una de las grandes ventajas de Ajax, que te permite enviar/recibir información al servidor sin tener que recargar la página. Cuando envías algo, inmediatamente el servidor procesa esa información o hace lo que le hayas indicado. Eso sí, el código PHP debe estar optimizado para que la respuesta sea más rápida. Si es algo muy pesado puede que tarde un poco, eso depende de la capacidad del servidor. Pero uno no se puede quedar *a idea fija*, por ejemplo hay gente que se empeña en traer miles de filas del servidor todas de golpe... ¿para qué? si no podrás leer al mismo...

Comment: ...tiempo miles de filas. Entonces hay que cambiar esa *idea fija*  y pensar en traer los datos por parte y presentarlos en forma de paginación o algo así. Digo esto porque a veces uno quiere respuestas rápidas, pero no tienes un procesador super potente como el de Google y tienes que adecuar tu código a las posibilidades que tienes... o hacer esperar al usuario para luego soltarle una cantidad ingente de información que él no sabrá qué hacer con ella. La optimización tiene varios niveles también, no es sólo el código, sino la base de datos, los archivos, la conexión del cliente, etc.

Comment: Otra manera sería que utilizaras rabbitmq. Haces tú gestión del formulario, preparas datos y generas un mensaje para rabbitmq. Haces un consumer para que con esos datos envíe los correos, y ese consumer lo programas para que se ejecute x ej cada 5min